# Call to a member function all() on string (View:

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a login page with [Laravel request validation method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)

And Credential verification -> if user is not authenicated it will return an error with 'wrong password ....'

I see errors in two different situation:-

1- When click on login button without filling any thing:-

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\nfbweb\resources\views\login.blade.php)
```

2- When fill a random/wrong username and password :

```
    ErrorException in f65ed669c524327dfe53b3286e027354370e4cf5.php line 13:
Call to a member function all() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\nfbweb\resources\views\login.blade.php)
```

This is my Login view file:-

```
 <h1>Login Page</h1>
@if (session()->has('errors'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            {{session('errors')}}
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<form action="{{route('dologin')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
    <br>
    Password:  <input type="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <button>Login</button>

</form>
```

This is my login controller :

```
    public function doLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://domainname/api/v1/']);

        try {

            $response = $client->request('POST', 'login', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,

                ],
            ]);
        }
        catch (ClientException $exception) {
            return back()->with('errors', 'Invalid username and/or password');
        }

}
```

I removed the authentication error message in view file

```
 @if (session()->has('errors'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            {{session('errors')}}
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The laravel request validator worked fine .

When i removed the validator error message in view file, the authenication error message worked !

Is there any conflict i made in both error message ?

How can i make both of them work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by changing the following :-
session('errors') to session('error')

there was a conflict in names of laravel validator session name , and the session name i set to return the authentication error message

Comment: I have the same problem. If you use with ->with('errors', 'your message'); It conflicts with validation errors. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors